# pref@item.Id is content with razor, I need it code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm doing something like

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
<li id='pref@item.Id' >
..
```

the problem is that it's rendered as content 'pref@item.Id' the item.Id is not evaluated, anybody knows a way out of this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Razor thinks you're trying to render an email address. Try one of these two approaches:

```
<li id='pref@(item.Id)'>

<li id='<text>pref</text>@item.Id'>
```

See this handy quick reference by Phil Haack for more tips:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx